# Pass ajax post request to php on other server

Tags: php, javascript

```
function doit(user)
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:'http://www.xxxxxx.in/index.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:{id:user},
        success:function(data){
            if(data == "true")
            {
                //ileti("success","Done");
            }
        }
     });
 }
```

This is my index.php :

```
$user = $_REQUEST["id"];
```

Why is it that the value isn't passing?

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($_REQUEST)`?

Comment: What do you mean by,"not passing"?

Comment: check on console or in firebug. What error do you get @Johan

Comment: *Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding** of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions**, **why they didn't work**, and the expected results.* Did you even take a look at what the AJAX call is returning to you? Did you take a look at the network response and also the console? What did they say? Did you get a network response code of 200? What was it? Your `datatype` should be set to `jsonp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to echo it out to return it to the AJAX function, and you might as well use $_POST,

```
echo $_REQUEST["id"]; // or
echo $_POST["id"];
```

Comment: I dont want it to return it to ajax I want to post that value from ajax to php and save it in database.

Answer (score 1):

As a security measure, AJAX does not allow you to make requests to other domains. If you still want to make a call on other server then do something like this.

The simplest way is first call a function on your own server and from that page use some other method like CURL to fetch data from other server. [Ajax to Different Server Using PHP](http://blog.rectorsquid.com/ajax-to-different-server-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

Do some debugging. Try this :-

`var_dump($_REQUEST);`

and see what you get as output.